# Why is React-Redux not calling action creator function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a piece of code which updates user settings when a number input box is called in react-redux.  The first portion of the code works fine:  The "onChange" function gets called.  But now it gets weird.  onChange is called twice and the code jumps through a bunch of the react back end, touches the action creator then execution skips the entire function and exits at the closing brace.

I have many other Redux functions created using the same model that work perfectly and cannot understand why this one is not being called.

Here is my code:

**mapDispatchToProps**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        SMSAdmin_Get_Users: () => { return dispatch(SMSAdmin_Get_Users()) },
        SMSAdmin_Load_User: (userId, userName, oldData = null, startVal = 0, number = 20) => 
        {
            return dispatch(SMSAdmin_Load_User(userId, userName, oldData, startVal, number))
        },
        SMSAdmin_Update_User: (user, province, credits) => { return  
            SMSAdmin_Update_User(user, province, credits) 
        },
        SMSAdmin_setCurrentUpload: (userName) => { return SMSAdmin_setCurrentUpload(userName) }
    };
}
```

**Calling Input**

```
     <Form.Control type="number"
        style={{ width: '100px' }}
        defaultValue={this.props.SMSAdmin.user.credits}
        id='numCredits'
        onChange={(e) => this.updateUser(e.target)}
     />
```

I know that in the input I don't need to pass in the event but included it should I need it in the future for some purpose.

**onChange function**

```
//this gets called twice when making a single change in the input box
    updateUser = () => {
        var province = document.getElementById("provinceId");
        var credits = document.getElementById("numCredits");
        var user = document.getElementById("lblUser");
        if (user && user.value !== '') { //safeguard to avoid trying to update nothing
//execution hits here once, then after the second hit proceeds into Redux code
            this.props.SMSAdmin_Update_User(user.value, province.value, credits.value);
        }
    }
```

**Redux action creator**

```
// Execution touches here
export const SMSAdmin_Update_User = (user, province, credits) => (dispatch) => {
//then here jumps to bottom
    dispatch(Actions.SMSAdmin_User_Updating());

    var data = { 'mode': 'UPDATE', 'user': user, 'province': province, 'credits': credits }
    var init = fetchInit();//copy to not modify the original
    init.method = "POST";
    init.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    var myReq = new Request('/dataAPI/SMS', init);

    return fetch(myReq)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error("Error " + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            var err = new Error(error.message);
            throw err;
        })
        .then((response) => { return response.json() })
        .then((resp) => {
            handleData(dispatch, Actions.SMSAdmin_User_Updated, resp)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            var msg = err.message;
            return dispatch(Actions.SMS_Send_Failed(msg));
        });
} //touches here and exits
```

I think that this is all the code involved.  If I am missing anything let me know and I will include it.  I am baffled how execution touches the function but does not execute it, nor does Chrome debug break at a breakpoint set on the function header.

Comment: Shouldn't you be dispatching `SMSAdmin_Update_User` like `SMSAdmin_Load_User` is dispatched in mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: @SunilChaudhary Well... that was simple :)  Thank you.  If you write it as an answer I can give you credit and others will be able to see it as the answer.  I missed that completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that action is not dispatched properly. *dispatch* is not attached to SMSAdmin_Update_User function.

Inside mapDispatchToProps, update the following:

```js
SMSAdmin_Update_User: (user, province, credits) => {
  // Add dispatch here. It is already done for other functions such as SMSAdmin_Load_User
  return dispatch(SMSAdmin_Update_User(user, province, credits))
},
```